# Unable to access app via ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes

I created a simple contour ingress controller for my simple go http web app listening on port 8000. I am unable to access the web app from  the browser without kubectl port forwarding via ingress controller.

Link to simple web app - https://github.com/shinychimra07/ramp/blob/main/main.go

Kind cluster- https://github.com/shinychimra07/ramp/blob/main/kind_config.yaml

Deployment- https://github.com/shinychimra07/ramp/blob/main/deployment.yaml

Sevice- https://github.com/shinychimra07/ramp/blob/main/service.yaml

Ingress- https://github.com/shinychimra07/ramp/blob/main/ingress.yaml

```
$ kubectl get ingress

NAME CLASS HOSTS ADDRESS PORTS AGE

simple-web-app <none> simple-web-app-local 80 36m

$ curl simple-web-app-local

curl: (7) Failed to connect to simple-web-app-local port 80 after 11 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I am unable to access the app from the browser without kubectl port forwarding via ingress controller.

Comment: The server running `curl simple-web-app-local` doesn't know the how to resolve the name simple-web-app-local unless you have specified it in `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: I have the host configured in /etc/hosts hence this should not be an issue. Also the curl command does not complain about the host

Comment: can you share the output of `nslookup simple-web-app-local` and also once it resolves to an IP, try `telnet <resolved-ip> 80`

Comment: @sibtain ```
nslookup simple-web-app-local
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find simple-web-app-local: NXDOMAIN
```
Ping is happening as expected
```
ping simple-web-app-local
PING simple-web-app-local (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms
```